# Inner join of 2 tables with the same ID

Tags: mysql, sql, join, inner-join

I have a table(`T1`) in which 2 columns(`X` and `Y`) are id's. The name's of these corresponding `id`'s are in another table (`T2`) with the column `name`.

Suppose I was only using `X` then, a simple Inner join would have solved my problem in getting the name.

Such as

```
Select T1.somedata,T1.somedata1,T2.name from T1
Inner Join T2 ON T1.X=T2.id
```

But,what if I want the name's to be resolved for the `T1.Y` also?, which `name` would the Inner Join resolve it to ??

```
Select T1.somedata,T1.somedata1,T2.name from T1
Inner Join T2 ON T1.X=T2.id
Inner Join T2 ON T1.Y=T2.id
```

The above query is wrong, I know. Can I get the `name`s of those corresponding to both `T1.X`and `T1.Y` with an `INNER Join`?

-Beginner

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I suggest always add aliases to tables and columns. So you will be sure which data are selected.

```
select
    T1.somedata,
    T1.somedata1,
    T2X.name as XName,
    T2Y.name as YName
from T1 as T1
    inner join T2 as T2X on T2X.id = T1.X
    inner join T2 as T2Y on T2Y.id = T1.Y
```

Answer (score 2):

This selects both names as separate columns:

```
Select T1.somedata,T1.somedata1,T2a.name, T2b.name 
from T1
Inner Join T2 as T2a ON T1.X=T2a.id 
Inner Join T2 as T2b ON T1.Y=T2b.id
```

The following would generate two records in the result set:

```
Select T1.somedata, T1.somedata1, T2.name
from T1
Inner Join T2 ON T1.X=T2.id Or T1.Y=T2.id
```

Answer (score 1):

you need to join table `T2` twice and supply aliases on the names to avoid ambiguity.

```
SELECT  a.*, 
        b.name as NameB, 
        c.name as NameC
FROM    T1 a
        INNER JOIN T2 b
            ON a.x = b.id
        INNER JOIN T2 c
            On a.y = c.id
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to join table T2 twice and supply aliases on the names to avoid ambiguity.

```
SELECT  a.*, 
        b.name as NameB, 
        c.name as NameC
FROM    T1 a
        INNER JOIN T2 b
            ON a.x = b.id
        INNER JOIN T2 c
            On a.y = c.id
```